# How to dynamically set model's table_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, rails-activerecord, class-variables

I have a legacy db (oracle), in that db I have several tables that hold different data but are structurally the same. I am not allowed to change the DB schema in any way!

I wanted a DRY ActiveRecord Model to fetch the right data from the right tables. The problem was that I needed to dynamically overwrite `self.table_name` in order for it work.

Here is my code:

**ActiveRecord:Base Class** which will be inherited by all similar tables

```
class ListenLoc < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@table_name = nil

  def self.table_name
    @@table_name
  end    

  default_scope { where(validated: 1).where("URL_OK >= 0") }
  scope :random_order, -> { order('DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE') }
  scope :unvalidated, -> { unscope(:where).where(validated: 0) }


  def self.get_category(cat_id)
    where("cat_id = ?", cat_id)
  end    

  def self.rand_sample(cat_id, lim)
    where("cat_id = ?", cat_id).random_order.limit(lim)
  end    
end
```

Child Classes look as such:

A

```
class ListenLocA < ListenLoc
  @@table_name = 'LISTEN_ADDR_A'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ListenLocCatA', foreign_key: 'cat_id'
  belongs_to :country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'country_id'
end
```

B.

```
class ListenLocB < ListenLoc
  @@table_name = 'LISTEN_ADDR_B'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ListenLocCatB', foreign_key: 'cat_id'
  belongs_to :country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'country_id'
end
```

The above works, however I have already noticed that there are some pitfalls when doing specific select lookups.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better way to pass the `self.table_name` dynamically?

**Update:**

One would think that this should work, but I get an error that the table does not exist since ActiveRecord tries to validate the table before creating an Object, and self.table_name is not set on the ListenLoc Model dynamically.

```
class ListenLocB < ListenLoc
  self.table_name = 'LISTEN_ADDR_B'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ListenLocCatB', foreign_key: 'cat_id'
  belongs_to :country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'country_id'
end
```

Comment: Personally I'd have different models for each table in your case.  You can extract the similar code in `ListenLoc` into a concern

Comment: In case someone needs to play with something similar in the future, see this Q&A:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537951/changing-table-name-at-query-run-time-in-a-rails-application/52539763#52539763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I realized is, that I could just use `superclass` without using globals, which I ended up using. This does not pose a race condition issue as with globals.

```
class ListenLocB < ListenLoc
  superclass.table_name = 'LISTEN_ADDR_B' # or ListenLoc.table_name
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ListenLocCatB', foreign_key: 'cat_id'
  belongs_to :country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'country_id'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby class variables are shared across whole hierarchy, so your approach will not work. General idea behind class variables - don't use it unless you are 100% sure you know what you are doing. And even when you are - there is most likely better approach.

As to actual issue - what you've done with `table_name` is not DRYing up, since you **added more lines than you saved**. Moreover, it makes it more difficult to read.

Just put

```
self.table_name =
```

where it should be in every model - it would be concise and readable.

Another option is to use localized constants instead which are bound to the `ListenLoc` class:

```
class ListenLoc
  def self.table_name
    TABLE_NAME
  end
end

class ListenLocB < ListenLoc
  ::TABLE_NAME = 'LISTEN_ADDR_B'
end
```

Why this works?

My understanding is the following:

By writing `::TABLE_NAME` you define the constant `TABLE_NAME` in the global scope.

When your call propagates to `ListenDoc` class, it tries to resolve the constant `ListenDoc::TABLE_NAME`, and it does not find it it's scope. Then it looks if the constant `TABLE_NAME` is defined in the outer scope, and it finds that `::TABLE_NAME` is indeed defined, and it's value is `'LISTEN_ADDR_B'`. Thus, works.

I might have been unclear, since my understanding on the topic still floats, but it is definitely related to how Ruby searches for constants.

It is not very straight forward, since few caveats exist (as with all, after all).

Comment: how did I add more lines than I saved? The class listenLoc has only a small extraction of methods included that would otherwise reside in the other models.

Comment: @mahatmanich I only meant the `table_name`/class variable part, other is actually fine (even though I might have  as well chosen concern over inheritance, as j-dexx suggests in comments, but that is up to you).

Comment: `self.table_name =`  in the actual models does not work, that is the issue. It is not propagated to ListenLoc even though it should! So the solution above is what I opted for.

Comment: @mahatmanich why is it putting table_name in each model not working?

Comment: See update, I need to actually reproduce the error to show the actual error message. self.table_name is not passed to ListenLoc properly.

Comment: uninitialized constant ListenLoc::TABLE_NAME :-/ No propagation to the parent class except class variables

my call: `ListenLocB.rand_sample(4,5)`

Comment: It makes it  to use absolute path to constant

Comment: I'll have to research that, but that would definitely be a better approach than class vars. I knew there was another way!

Comment: actually it needs to be the other way around as you edited it ... `::TABLE_NAME` on `ListenLocA` and then I can use `TABLE_NAME` in ListenLoc does not work the other way around!!

Comment: You're right, I edited via phone and misplaced the edit

Comment: WORKS FOR ME! Why? I don't know yet but thanks for the grand help!

Comment: Could you try to explain why this worked? Maybe update your Ans. That would be great!

Comment: @mahatmanich if you could give some time - I am now at work and we have a release, you know what that means.. :D I will updated the answer later, when will be at home. But that is all the matter of constants resolution mechanism in Ruby, you could read about it in the meantime

Comment: np :-) and will do. Good luck with the release!

Comment: @mahatmanich see the edit above. I hope I clarifies things at least a bit.

Comment: Yes it does clarify, however this is not going to work since globals are singularities. So if I have two requests at the same time for two different table models there is going to be a conflict and one of them is going to get false data due to race conditions.